# Generating multi-level JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of Objects, each containing a Location and a Links array of indeterminate length.  How can I create a multilevel JSON object with loops?

The end JSON should look like

```
item1: [
  { "location": [
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value }
    ],
   "links": [
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value }
    ]
  }   
],
item2: [ //repeat of above ]
```

The issue I'm having is how to correctly form the objects.  The objects that the array contains are defined as

```
function Links(){
  this.location = null;
  this.links= [];

  function getLocation(){
    return location;
  }
  function setLocation(marker){
    this.location = marker;
  } 

  function getLinks(){
    return links;
  }
}
```

My current solution is

```
var json=[];
var linkData;
for (var i=0; i < tourList.length; i++){
  var data = tourList[i];
  //create new child array for insertion
  var child=[];

  //push location marker data
  child.push({
    latitude: data.location.position.$a, 
    longitude: data.location.position.ab,
    stopNum: i,
    filename: data.location.title
  });

  //add associated link data
  for (var j=0; j<data.links.length; j++){
    linkData = data.links[i];
    child.push({
      latitude: linkData.position.$a, 
      longitude: linkData.position.ab,
      stopNum: i+j,
      fileName: linkData.title
    });
  }
  //push to json array
  json.push(child);
}

//stringify the JSON and post results
var results= JSON.stringify(json);
```

However, this is not quite working, as

```
$post= json_decode($_POST['json'])
```

PHP statement is returning a malformed array where `$post.length` is seen as an undefined constant.  I'm assuming that this is due to the incorrect formatting.

With objects defined above, how can I create a well-formed JSON to be sent to the server?

The current result of `stringify()` is

```
[
  {"latitude":43.682211,"longitude":-70.45070499999997,"stopNum":0,"filename":"../panos/photos/1-prefix_blended_fused.jpg"},
  [
    {"latitude":43.6822,"longitude":-70.45076899999998,"stopNum":0,"fileName":"../panos/photos/2-prefix_blended_fused.jpg"}
  ],
  {"latitude":43.6822,"longitude":-70.45076899999998,"stopNum":1,"filename":"../panos/photos/2-prefix_blended_fused.jpg"},
  [
    {"latitude":43.68218,"longitude":-70.45088699999997,"stopNum":1,"fileName":"../panos/photos/4-prefix_blended_fused.jpg"},
    {"latitude":43.68218,"longitude":-70.45088699999997,"stopNum":2,"fileName":"../panos/photos/4-prefix_blended_fused.jpg"}
  ]
]
```

Also, I'm using `$post.length` in

```
$post = json_decode($POST['json']);
for ($i=0; $i<$post.length; $i++) { }
```

to iterate over the processed array.

The POST request is via a `jQuery.ajax()` function defined as

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../includes/phpscripts.php?action=postTour",
  data: {"json":results},
  beforeSend: function(x){
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType){
      x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  },
  success: function(data){
    if (data == "success")
      console.log("Tour update successful");
    else 
      console.log("Tour update failed");

  }
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `count($post)` rather than `$post.length`?

Comment: Could you post a sample JSON output you get from that javascript? Also, how are you posting this to the PHP script?

Comment: Also, I believe you want to check for `strlen($post);` instead of `count();`.

Comment: @Andre, I added more information on both client and server side code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
var json = [];
var linkData;
for (var i = 0; i < tourList.length; i++) {
    var data = tourList[i];
    //create new child array for insertion
    var child = [{ }];

    //push location marker data
    child[0]['location'] = [{
        latitude: data.location.position.$a,
        longitude: data.location.position.ab,
        stopNum: i,
        filename: data.location.title
    }];

    child[0]['links'] = [];

    //add associated link data
    for (var j = 0; j < data.links.length; j++) {
        linkData = data.links[i];
        child.links.push({
            latitude: linkData.position.$a,
            longitude: linkData.position.ab,
            stopNum: i + j,
            fileName: linkData.title
        });
    }
    //push to json array
    json.push(child);
}

//stringify the JSON and post results
var results = JSON.stringify(json);
```

But why are you making the output JSON so complex? A simpler way would be to use something like this:

```
item1: {
    "location": {
        "latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value
    },
   "links": [
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "stopNum": value, "fileName": value }
    ]
},
item2: [ //repeat of above ]
```

What you are doing is creating 'arrays' for single objects. Why do that? If you use this format, the code (subtly) simplifies:

```
var json = [];
var linkData;
for (var i = 0; i < tourList.length; i++) {
    var data = tourList[i];
    //create new child array for insertion
    var child = { };

    //push location marker data
    child.location = {
        latitude: data.location.position.$a,
        longitude: data.location.position.ab,
        stopNum: i,
        filename: data.location.title
    };

    child.links = [];

    //add associated link data
    for (var j = 0; j < data.links.length; j++) {
        linkData = data.links[i];
        child.links.push({
            latitude: linkData.position.$a,
            longitude: linkData.position.ab,
            stopNum: i + j,
            fileName: linkData.title
        });
    }
    //push to json array
    json.push(child);
}

//stringify the JSON and post results
var results = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Comment: I was about to say that his JSON output was overly complicated and incorrect, you summed it up nicely before I could :)

Comment: Hey OP, did that work? (And btw, someone please tell me what's the full form of OP)

Comment: @ParthThakkar, that was the solution.  I know the JSON was a little complex, but I didn't see any way around it due to the contents of the objects.  Also, OP means Original Poster

Answer (score 1):

The answer, my friend, is `JSON.stringfy()`:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: `var results = var results= JSON.stringify(json);` Already doing that

Comment: So JSON.stringify is producing invalid JSON?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm getting a strange error server side that is a result of a `json_decode` operation that I know works for valid JSON.  So, I just want to make sure I'm producing correctly formatted JSON before sending to the server.

Comment: Well, if you're sure that the json object is valid (i.e. it is a JavaScript object), then JSON.stringify should work (unless it's a bug). Try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))` on the client-side, and see if it gives you the right object, so you can eliminate the problem from being in your JS.