# Decoding JSON and inaccessible variables

Tags: php, json

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122638/generating-multi-level-json/11122999#11122999) question, I had help in simplifying and forming a valid complicated JSON POST request.  However, I've now encountered some odd behavior server-side.

```
function postTour(){
  $post = json_decode($_POST['json'];
  $success = false;

  for ($i=0; $i<count($post); $i++){
    $filename = $post[i]['location']['filename'];

  }
}
```

Here, `$filename` is never initialized and never shows up as a variable in the debugger.  `$post` returns a multi-level array of the format

```
$post[3]
   [0] =>
       location = [ 5 key/value pairs ]
       links = one to n arrays

   [1] =>
       location = [ 5 key/value pairs],
       links = one to n arrays
```

In the debugger, each outermost array and location array has the type `stdClass`, while the links array has the type `array[n]`.  However, I can't access any information inside `$post`.  Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try passing `true` as a second argument to `json_decode()` in order to convert it to an actual array.

```
$post = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I saw the boolean option in the docs, but the example given was identical regardless of the boolean flag.  As a result, I didn't really appreciate the impact.

Comment: ya... one of the things about std class is that you can't just iterate through it like an array... its not so simple.